# How do I hide the DOCTYPE declaration for svg files generated by diagrams?

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams

I see that `generateDoctype` exists in the diagrams module: http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/haddock/diagrams-svg/Diagrams-Backend-SVG.html#v:generateDoctype

How do I set this to `false`?  Right now I am generating my svg file with `mathWith`, as recommended in the documentation, and I'm not sure where to put anything about `generateDoctype`.

Answer (score 1):

We can modify code copied from [here](https://github.com/diagrams/diagrams-svg/pull/85) to form a minimal case:

```
import Data.Text (empty)
import Diagrams.Prelude
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG

svgOpt :: Num n => Options SVG V2 n
svgOpt = SVGOptions {
  _size = mkSizeSpec $ V2 (Just 400) Nothing,
  _idPrefix = empty,
  _svgDefinitions = Nothing,
  _svgAttributes = [],
  _generateDoctype = False
}

diagram :: Diagram B
diagram = circle 1 # fc orange # lw ultraThick # lc blue # frame 0.2

main :: IO ()
main = renderPretty' "opts.svg" svgOpt diagram
```